# Oracle 11g parsing column with json string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I did not find any answer to all my googling on what i wanted. So please patiently read through my question . I have oracle 11g. I got a table with a varchar2 column which stores json string. I want to be able to query that column using sql query and parse out various data from side that json string. I found apex_json function but it can be used only inside pl/sql. I want something for sql query.

Comment: Just upgrade to 12c.

Comment: You need 12c to get new json support.

Comment: I work for a corporation. And it is not easy to get things upgraded in corporations. So is there a solution for 11G?

Answer (score 0):

one workaround that works for me is using regex:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            extra_data,
            '"application_number":\"?(.+?)\"?(}|,)',
            1, 1, 'i', 1) application_number,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            extra_data,
            '"related_application_number":\"?(.+?)\"?(}|,)',
            1, 1, 'i', 1) related_application_number,
        et.*
    FROM
        example_table et
)
WHERE
    application_number = to_char(2222)
```

In the example we want to bring all the example_table rows that in the column (that holds a json string) extra_data -> in application_number have the value 2222.

We also bring the values of application_number & related_application_number in the results as separate columns, the regex matches quoted or unquoted values.